# VBA - Concatenation Issues & reference a predetermined range

Tags: excel, vba, concatenation

I'm looking to simply input a formula into a cell which contains a concatenated text string combined with a function - I'm getting constant 1004 errors.

Desired formula in Cell

="https://internet.com/internet/ListWindow.aspx?"&CONCATENATEMULTIPLE(B3:B16,"")

works as expected in the excel sheet

In VBA I have

```
Sub IAS_AUTO_LIST()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set uRange = Application.Selection
    Set uRange = Application.InputBox("Select Range to Add Par ID Link", "Range", uRange.Address, Type:=8)
    Range("1").Select
  

    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=""https://internet.com/internet/ListWindow.aspx?WindowId=undefined""&CONCATENATEMULTIPLE(" & uRange & ","""")"

        

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

I don't think it likes the   multiple("    end of the first string.

Any help really appreciated

Comment: If you get an error 1004 - is there an error text with it? Please provide this too for a good question. And here you should have google'd already for such errors before you ask. E. g. Google found me already a suitable? [link, that could solve your problem](https://excelchamps.com/vba/runtime-error-1004/)... - but it seems that the error text can change with number 1004... so note it here.

Comment: Appreciate the quick response - Yes checked the errors, googled the hell out of it - tried all sorts. The formula I provided is what I feel should be correct, I can explicitly put the code in however it breaks the code at (" and I'm sure its due to the use of quotation marks throughout, I've tried other measures such using ch(34) etc....

Comment: Runtime error 1004: Application-defined or object-defined error

Comment: @dalyj And on which line do you get the error?

Comment: ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=""https://internet.com/internet/ListWindow.aspx?WindowId=undefined""&CONCATENATEMULTIPLE(" & uRange & ","""")"

Comment: The activecell.formulaR1C1 line

Comment: What is `CONCATENATEMULTIPLE` ?  A UDF you wrote?

Comment: Yep... I thought it shouldn't matter as all I'm doing is inserting text

Comment: `uRange` is a range object - did you mean to use `...&CONCATENATEMULTIPLE(" & uRange.Address() & ","""")"` ?

Comment: @TimWilliams I've tried that already - still gets an error, I believe that may be the correct for the range but not for the concatenation

Answer (score 2):

You're specifying that you're setting the formula with R1C1 references. So, you have to pass the address of `uRange` in R1C1 format. Also, CONCATENATEMULTIPLE isn't a built-in command, so I've used TEXTJOIN instead:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=""https://internet.com/internet/ListWindow.aspx?WindowId=undefined""&TEXTJOIN("""",TRUE," & uRange.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1) & ")"
```

Comment: Unfortunately I'm using Excel 2016 Hence I needed to create a custom TEXTJOIN

Comment: I've managed to pass this before I just think it has some to do with the quotation marks

This worked fine to me on another sub
`ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=CONCATENATEMULTIPLE(Table1[Column1],"""")"`